# Jquery appendto div class selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following html

```
<div class="options">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option selected"></div>
    <div class="info">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option"></div>
    <div class="info">Text2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I try jquery to move "info" class, which has the previous class "swatch-option selected", at the end of the closing div class "options"

So my final html should be like

```
<div class="options">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option selected"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option"></div>
    <div class="info">Text2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="info">Text</div>
</div>
```

The jquery I tried is the following but it does not move the `info` class, which has the previous class `swatch-option selected`

```
<script>
    require([
    'jquery'
    ], function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.selected.info').appendTo('.options');
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: You need a space between `.selected` and `.info` to make it mean a descendant. You're selecting an element that has *both* classes.

Comment: @Barmar, they are siblings, I've formatted the HTML

Comment: `.selected.info` means "Every element which is a member of **both** of those classes", not either of them.

Comment: `.class1.class2` means the element has to have *both* classes.   You *maybe* want `.class1 ~ .class2` (tilde, sibling selector) or `.class1 + .class2` (plus, next element).  See [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).  *Edit* yes, `$('.selected + .info').appendTo('.options');` would do what you want.

Comment: Are you trying to move _classes_ or _elements_? Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't put tags on it.

Comment: @isherwood Doesn't the final HTML in the question address that?

Comment: It was a rhetorical question to make the point that elements are not classes and vice versa. Also, the title is a vague mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.selected.info')` means to search for an element that has both `selected` and `info` classes but they are siblings in your example.

You can use [the adjacent sibling selector (+)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selected + .info').appendTo('.options');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="options">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option selected"></div>
    <div class="info">Text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swatch-option"></div>
    <div class="info">Text2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```